# Create a funnel in SQL with 30 days delay

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have table like this with hundreds of records :  month_signup, nb_signups, month_purchase and nb_purchases

| month_signup | nb_signups | month_purchase | nb_purchases |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 100 | 01 | 10 |
| 02 | 200 | 02 | 20 |
| 03 | 150 | 03 | 10 |

Let's say I want to calculate the signup to purchase ratio month after month.

Normaly I can juste divide **nb_purchases/nb_signups*100** but here no.

I want to calculate a signup to purchase ratio **with 1 month (or 30days) delay**.

To let the signups the time to purchase, I want to do the nb_purchase from month 2 divided by nb_signups from month_1. So 20/100 for exemple in my table.

I tried this but really not sure.

```
SELECT
month_signup
,SAFE_DIVIDE(CASE WHEN purchase_month BETWEEN signups_month AND DATE_ADD(signups_month, INTERVAL 30 DAY) THEN nb_purchases ELSE NULL END, nb_signups)*100 AS sign_up_to_purchase_ratio

FROM table

ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: Also, why you are using `month_signup, month_purchase` within the same table, while they seems to be the same?

Comment: Yes correct with this table, (month 01, 20/100) and (month02, 10/200). But in my real table I have much more rows.

Comment: It's because I originally joined two tables: Signups and Purchases, that have each one a date, to form this final table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `LEAD()` function to get the next value of the current row, I'll provide a `MySQL` query syntax for this.

```
with cte as 
(select month_signup, nb_signups, lead(nb_purchases) over (order by month_signup) as 
 nextPr from MyData
 order by month_signup)
 select cte.month_signup, (nextPr/cte.nb_signups)*100 as per from cte
 where (nextPr/cte.nb_signups)*100 is not null;
```

You may replace `(nextPr/cte.nb_signups)` with the `SAFE_DIVIDE` function.

See the demo from *[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/geDxYk3ec3U8pwzZ6mMoQg/0)*.